# Definition of structarality for predicate logics

Tags: logic, fuzzy-logic

A logic $L$ in a propositional language $\mathfrak{L}$ is said to be structural if $\Gamma\vdash_{L}\phi$, then $\sigma({\Gamma})\vdash_{L}\sigma({\phi})$ for each $\mathfrak{L}$ substitution $\sigma$ (an $\mathfrak{L}$ substitution being an endomorphism of $Fm_{\mathfrak{L}}$ and, the absolutely free algebra generated by $X$, say $X$ is countably infinite for this case. And $\Gamma\cup\{\phi\}\subseteq{Fm_{\mathfrak{L}}}$). How does this extend to the predicate case, i.e. a language $(\mathfrak{L},\mathfrak{P})$?

In http://www.carlesnoguera.cat/files/ch2.pdf (pg 182) the word logic is used in the same sense for predicate language (pg 177, 178 also carry relevant definitions) but it is not mentioned how the above property should be viewed. Basically what is the analouge of an $\mathfrak{L}$ substitution?

Comment: Is the [tag:fuzzy-logic] tag really appropriate here?

Comment: @HenningMakholm : Well, the main use of the question is to apply the definitions and obtain a completeness theorem for fuzzy logic.... so I felt it was at least semi appropriate.